# How to use user provided dates with yii db expression

Tags: php, oracle, activerecord, yii2

I am sending a user provided date in the format MM/DD/YYYY. Example 10/07/2020. I want to store this date in a column of type TIMESTAMP(0) in an oracle database.

I have this in my code:

```
$medicalClaimDetail = new MedicalClaimDetail();

$medicalClaimDetail->TREATMENT_DATE = new yii\db\Expression('10/07/2020');

$medicalClaimDetail->save();
```

However I get this exception:

```
Error Code : 932 Error Message : ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected TIMESTAMP got NUMBER Position
```

Answer (score 0):

using strings worked for me.

1. in db component config i had:

   ```
    'on afterOpen'      => function($event) {
        $event->sender->createCommand("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'")->execute();
        $event->sender->createCommand("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'")->execute();
    }
   ```
2. in code i set dates and timestamps as strings:

```php
        $medicalClaimDetail->TREATMENT_DATE = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
        $medicalClaimDetail->save();
```